# Incorrect HAML syntax?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haml

I'm trying to create a modal using HAML, so I was trying to make the code [here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) in HAML. I keep getting the error "ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.precompile. You passed true."

In my attempt to figure out the error, I went to haml2erb.herokuapp.com to see if I could find an error, but then that said I had the following error: "(line 1, column 70): unexpected "\"", expecting space, "(" or "[". Suffice it to say, I'm stumped. Here is my HAML:

```
.modal.fade#myModal{tabindex: -1, role: "dialog", aria: {labelledby: "myModalLabel", hidden: "true"}}
  .model-dialog
    .model-content
      .model-header
        %button.close{type: "button", data-dismiss="modal", aria-hidden="true"} X
        %h4.modal-title#myModalLabel Modal title
      .modal-body
        this is where all the cool stuff goes
      .modal-footer
        %button.btn.btn-default{type: "button", data-dismiss="modal"} Close
        %button.btn.btn-primary{type: "button"} Save changes
```

Comment: You’ve got a few `=` where I think you mean `:`.

Comment: I thought you could use either `=` or `:`. I used the `=` because `data-dismiss:` for example wouldn't work due to the `-`.

Comment: Yep, I just noticed the attributes are hyphenated. You have to use the old hash syntax with strings: `{"data-dismiss" => "modal"}` or you can use the HTML style Haml attributes: `(data-dismiss="modal")` (Note the `()` rather than `{}`. http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#htmlstyle_attributes_

Comment: You might be able to use underscores in the future which will be converted to hyphens, e.g. `data_dismiss: "modal"`, but that isn’t implemented yet: https://github.com/haml/haml/issues/782